# Vmware - How to disable Time Sync of Guest OS

Tags: vmware-esxi

Every time I power on/start VMWare guest OS, its date-time syncs with the Host OS. How do I disable it?

Comment: this syncing copes with several problems, be sure you want to do it before you turn it off.  The internal clock or ntp in the guest are not reliable

Answer (score 3):

Switch it off in the vmtools.